# How to apply these transformations to a line in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm not sure what tools I should use for what I'm trying to do since I'm only really familiar with SKSpriteNodes and a little bit with SKShapeNodes.

My mission is as follows:

- Add a line to the scene, SKShapeNode?
- Rotate the line along it's bottom point (beginning point?) by some angle. Imagine a clock hand for this, rotating around the bottom point
- Find the new point (x,y coord) of the top point (end point?) after the line has been translated

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I'm currently using an SKShapeNode for my line and rotating it with .zRotation but I can't seem to accomplish my goal. There doesn't seem to be an achorPoint property for SKShapeNodes, so I can't change the point of rotation. Also I'm clueless on how to find the position of the end point of my line AFTER it has been rotated, I created it as follows:

```
        let linePath = CGMutablePath()
        linePath.move(to: begin)
        linePath.addLine(to: end)

        let line = SKShapeNode()
        line.path = linePath
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        line.lineWidth = 5
        SceneCoordinator.shared.gameScene.addChild(line)
```

I'm rotating using:

```
     public func rotate(angle: Double) {
        var transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))
        line.path = linePath.mutableCopy(using: &transform)
    }
```

Comment: hey there, did my answer help you? If not, let me know so I can try to update it for you.

Answer (score 0):

SKShapeNode can be pretty expensive if you notice your FPS dropping. Also, you can easily turn a shape into a sprite to get `.anchorPoint`, but be warned that anchorpoint's behavior is not always as expected and you may have bugs later on (especially with physics):

```
func shapeToSprite(_ shape: SKShapeNode) -> SKSpriteNode {
  let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKView().texture(from: shape))
  sprite.physicsBody = shape.physicsBody // Or create a new PB from alpha mask (may be slower, IDK)
  shape.physicsBody = nil
  return sprite
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
  let shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 60)
  let sprite = shapeToSprite(shape)
  sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint()
  addChild(sprite)
}
```

Otherwise, you are going to have to either 1), redraw the line with the correct rotation, 2), rotate the shape then reposition it at a new location...

Both are going to be MATH :[ so hopefully the anchorppoint works for you